Need Help: Retag of [mining]
What's happening?
mining has been deprecated and all questions where it appears are getting retagged.
Why?
Mining is a central topic in cryptocurrencies. It deserves more than one tag. By separating different aspects of mining into their own collections users will be able to find related content more easily.
Who?
Anyone can help! If you can't edit yourself, you can suggest edits! Each suggested edit gives you +2 reputation when accepted.
How?

Find any questions tagged with mining.
Read questions and answers to figure out what the topic is.
Replace mining with tags from the following list.

Bonus: Where appropriate vote, edit for quality, add answers, or flag. Questions that are edited are bumped to the front. That's a great time to fix 'em up.
(Likely) Targets


miner-configuration
Collects questions about configuration of mining hardware, and optimizing the software settings of mining rigs.
mining-hardware
Collects questions about mining rigs, cpus, gpus, fpgas, and asic miners, as well as the production, and producers of such.
mining-pools
Questions about organizing groups to collaboratively work on block creation.
mining-profitability
Collects questions about the economics of mining operations.
mining-theory
Questions about the function, the reason for, and the underlying concepts of mining.
cpu-mining
Questions about using CPUs for mining.
gpu-mining
Collects questions about mining setups on basis of GPUs.
pool-payout-methods
Questions about sharing revenue in mining pools.
shares
Shares refers to a method for accounting mining pool contributions. It does not cover company shares. 
solo-mining
refers to mining by yourself, not organized in a mining-pool 
mining-software
General questions about mining software.
mining-setup
Is used for questions concerned with the physical setup of mining hardware.
miner-configuration
Collects questions about configuring and optimizing the software settings on mining rigs.
mining-technical-details
Is used for questions on the technical process of building a block header, and what gets hashed in mining.

When?
Starting now, until there are no questions left with the tag mining. :)

this is a hell of task. is this really needed?

@5chdn: Needed? I'm not sure. Worth it? Maybe. An improvement? Very likely.

Progress report!

2016-01-20: I've retagged 56 questions that had mining and profitability on them. → 1347 questions left. ;)
2016-01-21: Some more retagging done. → 1314 left. Review of hashrate vs hashpower initiated.
2016-01-22: Retagged merged-mining. → 1284 left.
2016-01-23: Merged build into compiling, added a few tag excerpts, started retagging cpu+mining. → 1274 left.
2016-01-27: 1257 left.
2016-02-01: 1243 left.
2016-02-02: Revised tag wikis of stale-block and orphaned-blocks. Added empty-blocks, transaction-propagation. → 1216 left.
2016-02-04: 1197 left.
2016-02-08: 1156 left.
2016-02-12: 1132 left.
2016-02-15: 1120 left.
2016-02-17: 1107 left.
2016-02-21: 1049 left.
2016-03-06: 993 left.
2016-03-09: 958 left.
2016-03-10: 904 left.
2016-03-11: 876 left.
2016-03-14: 850 left.
2016-03-15: 822 left.
2016-03-16: 751 left.
2016-03-17: 719 left.
2016-03-18: 708 left.
2016-03-31: 616 left. Woohoo, more than half finished.
2016-04-02: 559 left.
2016-04-09: 517 left.
2016-04-10: 444 left.
2016-04-10: 368 left.
2016-04-24: 278 left.
2016-04-25: 102 left.
2016-04-28: 0 left. Will be requesting mining to be blacklisted.

